# How can I set a parent of an object in the BGE using python?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have two objects

A a box

and

B a sphere.

I want to make B A's child.

how can this be done in the BGE, using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = own.scene

objA = scene.objects["objA"]
objB = scene.objects["objB"]

objB.setParent(objA)
```

### **setParent**(*parent, compound=True, ghost=True*)

Sets this object’s parent. Control the shape status with the optional
compound and ghost parameters. In that case you can control if it should be ghost or not.

- **parent** (*[KX_GameObject](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html)*) – new parent object.
- **compound** (*boolean*) – whether the shape should be added to the parent compound shape.

  - *True*: the object shape should be added to the parent compound shape.
  - *False*: the object should keep its individual shape.
- **ghost** (*boolean*) – whether the object should be ghost while parented.

  - *True*: if the object should be made ghost while parented.
  - False: if the object should be solid while parented.

Source: [Blender 2.79 API Documentation, bge.types.KX_GameObject section](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.setParent)

Comment: thanks this is perfect.